# Проверка пользователя(Расширения), если его id в списке на сервере?

Tags: javascript

Как реализовать условие проверка txt файла(Либо другого) есть ли в файле его id? Если id пользователя есть в списке на сервере, то функция в условии выполняется, а если id нет в списке, выводится окошко.

Не знаю как реализовать список с нужными id. И как брать оттуда данные для сравнения.

Comment: что-то я не пойму в чем проблема. На сервере у вас есть файл. Отправляйте запрос содержащий id на сервер, отлавливайте и проверяйте

Comment: А как реализовать это программно? Теоритический то я знаю как это все работает, запросом ajax я отправляются запрос который содержит id вроде как. А все что должно быть на самом сервере я незнаю как сделать

Comment: "И как брать оттуда данные для сравнения." тут я признаться не понял о чем речь. Поэтому описал только схему о которой говорил выше

Comment: @UserName брать данные с файла txt, там одна большая строка с цифрами через запятую

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Должно быть что-то вроде этого:

На сервере должен быть скрипт который который будет принимать запрос и отдавать ответ.

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

if ($_GET["id"]) {
    echo "ID" . $_GET["id"] . "присутствует в базе!";
}
```

Выше приведен примитивный пример. Устанавливаем заголовок `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`. Его установка означает что сервер разрешает кросс-доменный запрос. Если его не будет, браузер его не получит и завершит запрос ошибкой.

Далее выполняем примитивную проверку `id`, который будет отправлен из расширения.

Проверяем `GET` массив. Ага, id передан. Выводим сообщение. Т.е вывод конструкции `echo` будет передан в качестве ответа.

В действительности же у вас будет продвинутая обработка. Т.е не просто смотреть на наличие `GET["id"]`, а проверять наличие в файле итп.

В расширении должно быть что-то вроде:

```
var xmlHttpRequest = (function () {

    var _xmlHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();


    function sendRequest(url) {

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

            _xmlHttpRequest.onload = function () {

                resolve(_xmlHttpRequest.responseText);
            };

            _xmlHttpRequest.onerror = function () {

                reject(_xmlHttpRequest.statusText);
            };

            _xmlHttpRequest.open("get", url, true);

            _xmlHttpRequest.send();
        });
    }


    return {

        sendRequest: sendRequest
    }
})();
```

Вызывать все это дело можно так:

```
xmlHttpRequest.sendRequest("http://localhost?id=1").then(function (result) {

    alert(result);
});
```

Параметр функции `sendRequest` замените на свой. Я проверял на своем компьютере, поэтому указал `localhost`.

Тут мы отправляем get запрос на указанный адрес и ждем результата выполнения. Как только будет получен ответ от сервера, вы увидите всплывающее окно.

Ссылки:

[Основы XMLHttpRequest](https://learn.javascript.ru/ajax-xmlhttprequest)

[XMLHttpRequest: кросс-доменные запросы](https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain)

[Обещания JavaScript](https://habrahabr.ru/post/209662/) (это касательно `new Promise` в коде выше)

**UPD**

> брать данные с файла txt, там одна большая строка с цифрами через
>   запятую

Ну значит сделайте что-то вроде:

```
if($_GET["id"]) {

    $data = file_get_contents("data.txt");

    $data = explode(",", $data);

    if(array_search($_GET["id"],$data) !== false    ) {

        echo "ID" . " " . $_GET["id"] . " " . "присутствует в файле";
    }
}
```

Смотрим есть ли `id`. Если есть, то читаем файл. Содержимое файла преобразуем в массив(`explode` преобразовывает строку в массив используя разделитель `","`).

Далее проверяем наличие пришедшего `id` в массиве используя функцию `array_search`.

Ссылки:

[array_search](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.array-search.php)

[explode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.explode.php)

> но вот что выводит консоль браузера при запросе Promise { :
>   "pending" }

Если вы читали то, что я скинул то могли заметить:

> Обещание может быть:  fulfilled — успешно завершённым  rejected —
>   завершённым с ошибкой  pending — не завершённым  settled — завершённым
>   с любым исходом

[Схема состояний. Изображение](https://mdn.mozillademos.org/files/8633/promises.png)
[Еще о promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)

Comment: Запрос должен быть таким? 
`xmlHttpRequest.sendRequest("file:///C:/test.php?id=1").then(function (result) {

    alert(result);
});`

Comment: а php файл я сделал таким, сам в php разбираюсь очень плохо, надеюсь правильно
`<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

$file = file_get_contents('2.txt');

if (preg_match($_GET["id"], $file) {
    echo "ID" . $_GET["id"] . "присутствует в базе!";
}
?>`

Comment: но вот что выводит консоль браузера при запросе *Promise { <state>: "pending" }*

Comment: @SloGS, обновил ответ